# HOWTO add new tab and fields to tx_news

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, tx-news

Hi my problem is that I need to do a new extension depending on tx_news.
I want to add a TAB to the plugin options (after template tab) with some fields
I looked for the solution, but I can find only instruction to add a new field within the news record, but not for the plugin options.

typo3 v9.5 + tx_news v 7.x+

Answer (score 0):

Until now there is no mechanism to add fields to the flexform definition which makes up the plugin options.

So you have to provide a complete flexform definition where you still use the old definition. that will break if the original extension changes it's flexform (and change something evidently).

Comment: thank you. maybe I'm in wrong but I found this (that's not work for me):

https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/7.3/en-us/DeveloperManual/ExtendNews/ExtendFlexforms/Index.html

so that I should use a hook to submit some new fields.

have a look to the secition

Extend flexforms with custom fields